# Is it possible to distribute python package in pkg_add understandable tbz format

Tags: package, freebsd, puppet

I am trying to distribute packages in tbz format so that pkg_add can install it. I am aware that easy_install can do the same trick with egg format but I want to use puppet to install it which in turn has packages which expects tbz format for freebsd because package uses pkg_add in freebsd to install packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to create a port for your app. After that you can run `make package` in your port dir to create tbz package.

For information on creating ports see Porters Handbook (http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/) and of course other python ports.